# Python: aiohttp responses delayed when receiving concurrent requests

Tags: python, jmeter, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using `aiohttp` for the first time in my python app for web server. I try to upload an image to the server, do some processing and return the response. Here is the code

```
@routes.post('/')
    async def handle(request: web.Request) -> web.Response:
        reader = await request.post()
        path = os.getcwd()
        filename = reader['file'].filename
        fn = os.path.join(path, filename)
        try:
            out = open(fn, 'wb')
            out.write(reader['file'].file.read())
            res = do_processing(fn) #This method is in another file
            response = json.dumps({'data': res[0]})
            print(response)
        except IOError as e:
            print(e)
            return web.Response(body="{\"error:\"Error\"}")
    
        return web.Response(body=response)
    
    
    def run_server():
        app = web.Application()
        app.router.add_post('/', handle)
        web.run_app(app, port=8080)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        run_server()
```

This works fine. However, I tried to do some load testing using `jmeter` with 20 users. I notice that even though the requests keep getting executed, `jmeter` doesn't receive the response at the same time.

The `print(response)` output keeps printing in the log but jmeter shows just 1 request as successful. And then, in the end, jmeter shows all requests finished at the same time.

During this time if I call the api from postman I have to wait. So I have two doubts

1. Why is `jmeter` not getting the response back when the request has finished? Why does it get the response as a bulk in the end
2. Is `aiohttp` blocking by default? I was assuming that if I call this from `postman` the request should finish in normal execution time. But it only finishes when all `jmeter` requests have finished execution

How can I resolve these 2 issues? Would appreciate any response/help. Thanks!!

Comment: aiohttp isn't blocking but your code is. Aside from the initial `await request.post()`, it doesn't await anything. Once `handle` receives the POST data, control is never yielding back to the event loop until it returns a `Response`. It's quite possible that aiohttp never receives control from the event loop to return that `Response` until all of the other requests are done. If you don't have significant I/O to perform, asyncio won't help you much. If nothing else you can use `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to yield back, but you'd probably benefit more from using something other than asyncio.

Comment: @dirn Thanks for the response. The code I used seems to be mentioned in several tutorials and even aiohttp docs.https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html So I was assuming this should work. 

I tried adding await asyncio.sleep(0) but still doesn't work as expected (unless I'm doing something wrong). Is there a way I can yield back to the event loop manually?

Comment: Awaiting `asyncio.sleep` is how you yield back manually. Where did you try using it? Please update the question.